# Check if an array can be put in another array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I am working on a PHP script to create an arduino "Tetris Clock". I would like to generate a sequence of blocks tetris to display a number.

My number array (example with "0") : (formated for display)

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Where :

```
1 = must be filled
0 = empty
2 = informed (after check if block can be put)
```

Now I have tetris block array, like that :

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
```

OR

```
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

and I want to check if I can **put my tetris block in number array**.

eg. : after placing the first block I would get the following array : (it's a "T" block)

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 2 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 1 1 1
```

At first I tried cutting tables in rows and columns to see if it corresponds with my block and I made ​​many changes without success.

You can see my two test scripts : http://pastebin.com/znnmvT4g and http://pastebin.com/D9h51Xw3

I will keep the historical additions to use backtracking in case of error or failure to resolve the number.

I would therefore firstly check if my blocka rray can be added to my number array.

Thank you for your ideas !

Comment: 1) What's your question? 2) What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Place your tetris block in an array with the exact same size as the number array and surround it with only zero's to define it's place on the board. (Notice I use 2's instead of 1's, this will be explained later on)

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
2 2 2 2 0 0
```

Then add all the existing array values to the corresponding values in the other array.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 3 1 1 1 1
5 5 5 3 1 1
```

Check if the resulting array contains a 5. If it does, the tetris block can't be placed in that position, because there is already a block there.

Also check if there are no 2's. If so, than a space that should not be filled is filled.  (here is why you should use 2's instead of 1's).

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
3 3 2 2 1 1
1 3 1 1 1 1
3 3 3 1 1 1
```

if none of these are true, you have a posible solution.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
3 3 3 3 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 3 1 1 1 1
3 3 3 1 1 1
```

This may not be the only solution, so you will have to do this for all the posible places the tetris block can be in the number array. To get the best place and create a posible solution you may want to use an algoritm like A*.